# How does nn.CrossEntropy ' s ignore_index implemented?

Tags: mask, loss-function

In pytorch, `nn.CrossEntropy` has a parameter: `ignore_index`.
How is it implemented?

Maybe like this? "compute CE loss with torch, but not use the function `nn.CrossEntropy`"

Answer (score 1):

The loss is simply set to 0 for the values with the ignored index.

In PyTorch, `nn.CrossEntropy` uses [negative log likelihood](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/2981534f54d49fa3a9755c9b0855e7929c2527f0/aten/src/ATen/native/LossNLL.cpp#L568).
It has several implementations, for example [this one](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/f37ce948ff25bf70a52ab4b327c82925ddb4aa86/aten/src/ATen/native/cuda/Loss.cu#L193).
Perhaps these lines are the most important for you:

```c
if (cur_target == ignore_index) {
  output[index] = static_cast<scalar_t>(0);
  continue;
}
```